# Django model edit page creates new model instead of editing the current one

Tags: django

I just deployed my first Django app, which is for the small company I work for to track jobs, expenses, and it has a blog for customers to see. After I deployed the site, I realized the page to edit the job model did not show the job's information but a blank form for a new instance. When the edit is submitted it creates a new instance instead of changing the current job that's meant to be edited. Editing works just fine through the admin dashboard, but I just can't figure out why the edit page won't work.

I tried tweaking the view function for editing the job, deleting migrations and the database, and re-migrating, all to no avail.

**views.py**

```
def job_edit(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=pk)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = JobForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                job = form.save(commit=False)
                job.author = request.user
                job.last_updated = timezone.now()
                job.image0 = form.cleaned_data['image0']
                job.image1 = form.cleaned_data['image1']
                job.image2 = form.cleaned_data['image2']
                job.image3 = form.cleaned_data['image3']
                job.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Job updated successfully')
                return redirect('job_detail', pk=job.pk)
        else:
            form = JobForm()
        return render(request, 'job_edit.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'job_edit.html')
```

**forms.py**

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foreman = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FOREMEN, required=True)
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=JOB_STATUS, required=True)
    zip = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(00000), MaxValueValidator(99999)])
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('title', 'foreman', 'crew_size', 'status', 'text', 'truck', 'trailer', 'service', 'client_name', 'client_phone', 'client_email', 'client_source', 'estimated_days', 'schedule_date', 'address', 'town', 'state', 'zip', 'image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `ModelForm` to edit an existing record you should pass the existing record to the form.

```
# When rendering the form on a GET
# This will populate the form with the jobs current data
form = JobForm(instance=job)

# When the form has been submitted
form = JobForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=job)
```